# Combine 2 CASE statements inside SELECT - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, case

i am using this sql block right now

```
SELECT mail_id,
  CASE consignor
    WHEN 'aby' THEN 
      'con'
    ELSE 
     'rec'
  END AS type,

CASE consignor
  WHEN 'aby' THEN 
    recipient
  ELSE 
    consignor
END AS other,

mail, mail_time 
FROM mail m
WHERE m.consignor = user OR m.recipient = user
ORDER BY mail_time DESC
```

As you can see 2 case statements does exactly same job here so i thought i somehow can combine them. However my attemps did not yield any results. Anyone knows something better here?

What i've tried?

```
SELECT mail_id,
  CASE consignor
    WHEN 'aby' THEN 
      'con', recipient
    ELSE 
      'rec', consignor
  END AS ( type, other ),

mail, mail_time 
FROM mail m
WHERE m.consignor = user OR m.recipient = user
ORDER BY mail_time DESC
```

Comment: No, you cannot use that shorthand.  A `case` *expression* returns one value, as with any other scalar expression in SQL.  `case` *statement* is something else entirely:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html.

Comment: Your "tried" version won't even run, and there is nothing wrong with those two `CASE` expressions if you want to have two separate columns in your output.  Stick with what you already have working.